# I have a vector with over 100 slightly different URLs, how to scrape without manually writing lines for every URL

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to create a dataset of penalty shoot-outs in the German cup by scraping data from `www.transfermarkt.de`.
I managed to scrape some data and put them together, however, the variable I need next is on a different webpage for every observation.
The variable I need next is the division in which the club played when they had the penalty shoot-out.

Luckily, transfermarkt.de is pretty ordered and you can get every homepage needed by only slightly changing the URL.

The URL structure looks as following: https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/105/saison_id/2001

x is just a placeholder, there could also be a 'z' or anything else

105 is the ID of the club

2001 is the id of the season (so in which particular season the club had the penalty shoot-out).

I have 132 observations so I possibly need 132 different URLs with different club and season id.

I'll upload also my table so you get a good overview. Click [here](https://gofile.io/?c=Q7RrRJ).

I can generate a vector containing all the URLs, but I don't know how to read the Html of every URL and get the division information at once.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)
library(stringr)

link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein'
rrr = paste(link, id_heim, "saison_id", Jahr, sep = "/") #id_heim is the           club id of the home team, 'Jahr' is the year.

read_html(rrr) #error message because of more than 1 string
```

rrr is a vector with 132 values, corresponding with my table

it looks like this

```
> head(rrr)
[1] "https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/16/saison_id/2018"   
[2] "https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/30/saison_id/2018"   
[3] "https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/3/saison_id/2018"    
[4] "https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/25/saison_id/2018"   
[5] "https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/23826/saison_id/2017"
[6] "https://www.transfermarkt.de/x/startseite/verein/25/saison_id/2017"
```

read_html(rrr) gets me this:

> Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
>    Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=132].

Thanks for any help or advice in advance.

EDIT: Traceback of the error

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403. 
14.
open.connection(x, "rb") 
13.
open(x, "rb") 
12.
read_xml.connection(con, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = as_html, 
base_url = x, options = options) 
11.
read_xml.character(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
options = options) 
10.
read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options) 
9.
withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w)       
invokeRestart("muffleWarning")) 
8.
suppressWarnings(read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
options = options)) 
7.
read_html.default(x) 
6.
read_html(x) 
5.
eval(lhs, parent, parent) 
4.
eval(lhs, parent, parent) 
3.
read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".box .table-header") %>% html_text() %>% 
.[5] %>% substr(., 20, nchar(.) - 6) %>% as.character() 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(rrr, function(x) {
Sys.sleep(5)
read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".box .table-header") %>% html_text() %>% 
    .[5] %>% substr(., 20, nchar(.) - 6) %>% as.character() ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(rrr, read_html)
```

What this does is running an (internal) loop over all links and using `read_html` one by one. The final result is then a list where each component is the result for one of the links.

If you want to create breaks between the function calls try this:

```
lapply(rrr, function(x) {Sys.sleep(2); read_html(x)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Denis @Cettt. Unfortunately I get an error message
    `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.`
Becuase I want to access to a page too often?
Is there a possibility to create a lag(e.g. 2 seconds) in between?

Comment: Hi, you can use `Sys.sleep(2)` like this: 
`lapply(rrr, function(x) {Sys.sleep(2); read_html(x)}`

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error message. I've also tried with `Sys.sleep(3)` and `Sys.sleep(5)`
Could it be something else?

I extended my code to the final output, I hope this isn't a problem.
`lapply(rrr, function(x) {Sys.sleep(5); read_html(x) %>% html_nodes('.box .table-header') %>% html_text() %>% .[5] %>% substr(.,20,nchar(.)-6) %>% as.character()})`

Comment: It's the same error message as previously
`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403. `
But now I can click on "Show Traceback" on the console. Unfortuanetly the traceback text is too long to post it here in the comments. I will post it in my main post.

Comment: No, it works. I also noticed that, after using 'lapply' and receiving the error message, I can't access to transfermarkt.de at all (on my webbrowser). It's like they temporarily disable my ip-address on their server (I am not an expert in these topics).

After a few minutes it works again.

I could try with `Sys.sleep(10)` and then wait about 15 minutes.

Comment: Didn't work. Got the following error message:
`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received `

Comment: Maybe you are behind a firewall? Or the site has really blocked your ip address. Hard to hell from here.

Answer (score 1):

How about `lapply(rrr, read_html)`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23550779)

Comment: Excuse me @EricHauenstein ? How does it not provide an answer to the question?